# Intersection with a plane and a simple closed curve

Tags: geometry

Let $C:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a simple closed curve. Can we always find a plane $H\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $H\cap C$ contains at least 4 points?

Actually, if we consider non-closed curve, there exists such curve : $C(t)=(t, t^2, t^3)$. (By fundamental theorem of algebra) Also I think the number 4 is efficient since the boundary of Pringles may not satisfy the 5-point intersection condition. (It is just my guess.)

I think it is true for closed curve since we may find some appropriate direction of normal vector of the plane $H$ and just move toward the curve until it meets at 4 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Most" planes will intersect the curve an even number of times. If a plane intersects the curve an odd number of times, they must be tangent at some point. We can certainly slightly perturb the plane to make it intersect the curve transversally, this increases the number of points of intersection by one.

Since it is easy to find a plane passing through three distinct points of the curve, we can find a plane passing through four.

This works when the curve is smooth, and I would be surprised if it didn't for nastier curves but I don't know enough to say for certain.